# How to insert a string containing '%' using QSqlQuery?

Tags: sqlite, qt, qsqlquery

I am trying to insert a string which contains '%' using QsqlQuery but I am always getting an error of type QSqlError::TransactionError with the message

```
"near "%": syntax error Unable to execute statement"
```

I have tried several ways to escape the "%" but I am still getting that error message. Please see the code snippet below.

```
query.exec(QString("INSERT INTO my_table (name, address) VALUES (\"%1\", \"%2\")")
                  .arg("Harry", "#302%%1,..."));
```

In place of "%%", I have tried "\%", "\%", but still it didn't work and I am having the same error message.

Comment: Have you tried the double-%? I've had to escape my QStrings that way on a couple occasions.

Comment: Yes I tried double-% as well as "\%" & "\\%" but nothing worked. It works fine on sqlite3 command line though with just quotes around the string.

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried wrapping your query in escaped quotes?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I just edited my question to add the code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, strings are delimited with `'`, not `"`.

Anyway, you should use parameters:

```cpp
query.prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (name, address) VALUES (?, ?)");
query.addBindValue("Harry");
query.addBindValue("#302%%1,...");
query.exec();
```